# graph api to fetch the coordinates of all the tagged photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photos, feed

I have just started working of facebook graph api v2.1.I know how to get all the tagged photos of a user or myself .I want to know how to fetch the coordinates of tags from all the photos that I am tagged in

Comment: Could you please provide the code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: me/photos?type=tagged ... by using this i can get all the tagged photos